# Buildbot behind an Apache proxies - Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) with mod proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, buildbot

I am using buildbot ( trac.buildbot.net ) to which clients connect through a proxy (installed on the same machine as buildbot server). Buildbot has an internal webserver of its own which is being served via proxy. To sum it up:

client browser -> Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) with mod proxy -> buildbot internal webserver

The problem:

Buildbot has a featurewhere, while a process in running on some slave, it's possible to read the logs in real time with a web browser. This is usually referred to as "Log streaming"
The above feature seems to have stopped working by the time the Apache proxy was set before Buildbot. The page just doesn't load, the browser's loading icon is all I can se. Upon step/task's complition, I can open it. Without the proxy, everything goes back to functioning.

Log streaming does not seem to be new to troubles when used together with a proxie. I've been in touch with the buildbot guys for a while now and after having tried all the most common fixes, we've come to the conclusion this is more of an Apache question.

To be more precise, many have been able to get past the issue by tweaking the ProxyIOBufferSize directive. Messing around with ProxyReceiveBufferSize did not help either.

Buildbot exposes its web at http:// buildbot/global/ In buildbot configuration terms:

```
HTTP_PORT = 'tcp:19811:interface=127.0.0.1'
EXTERNAL_URL = 'http://buildbot/global/'
```

and the proxy (running on the smae machine!) is set up the following way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
ProxyPass /global/ http://localhost:19811/
ProxyPassReverse /global/ http://localhost:19811/
```

Any hint would be hugely welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I'm totally guessing here, but any chance using a FQDN would help, something like "http://buildbot.foo.com/global/"?